# I am not getting photo library in ios5

Tags: iphone, photolibrary

It is not possible to get photo library from my application when running application in ios5. Is any body have solution for this?

Comment: What is te problem you're having with the Photo library? It's a bit unclear from you current question.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine - just call

```
UIImagePickerController* imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init]autorelease];

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[imagePicker takePhoto];
```